# Eduroam, wpa2-enterprise, wifi connection - Configuration options for the wpa_supplicant.conf file

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wpa

In attemting to get wifi configured for Model B, I'm editing the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`file in line with [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) and [this](http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/).

The network to which I'm connecting is asking me to set the following configuration:

- Wireless Network Name (SSID) :       netname
- Security Type :      WPA2-Enterprise
- Encryption Type :    AES (CCMP)
- EAP Method :     PEAP
- Phase 2 (Inner Method) :     EAP-MSCHAPV2
- Root CA Certificate(s) :      Install Organizational CA
- Server name :    radius.do.ma.in
- User Certificate :       N/A
- Anonymous Identity (Outer Identity) :    Leave Blank
- Username (Identity) :    username
- Password :       Password

my attempt thus far is:

```
network={
    ssid="netname"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise = CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    username="username"
    psk="Password"
```

When I click on the network name I get a dialog box with the following:

> Faile(sic) to reconfigure

I cannot seem to find a reference file to allow me to translate this.

**Is there a man reference for this?**

**What parameters do I need to add to `network={..}` to get this to work?**

Answer (score 2):

You don't need psk=, you want password=.  And at a minimum you need the following additional entries:

```
eap=PEAP
phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
ca_cert="/etc/cert/your_ca_cert.pem"
identity="user@example.com"
```

Full wpa_supplicant documentation is here: http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a man reference for this?

Yes.  At the end of `man wpa_supplicant` you will find a **SEE ALSO** list that includes `man wpa_supplicant.conf`.  That has various examples but "for  detailed  information about the configuration format and supported fields" you are supposed to look at "the example configuration file, probably in /usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/".

On Raspbian, there's actually an "examples" subdirectory instead, including one big one that contains detailed comments about (presumably) every potential field.

However, it is gzipped, so an easy way to view it is:

```
gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf.gz | less
```

You can also just use `gunzip` without the `-c` and `| less` at the end to unzip it then view as a normal text file however you like.