# Internet connection via wired link to Wndows7 PC laptop with wifi connection

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet, windows

Unfortunately, thus far, [I have been unable to configure my Raspberry Pi Model B to access the internet via a WPA-Enterprise connection.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50281/wifi-connection-configuration-options-for-the-wpa-supplicant-conf-file)

I do have access to a Windows7 laptop with a working wifi link however.

**Is there a simple way to piggy back an internet connection for a Model B Pi via an ethernet link to a Windows7 laptop?**

What are the steps I need to go through to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the Pi to your laptop via an Ethernet cable (regular, not a crossover). Go to "Network And Sharing Centre" on the laptop. On the left, click Change Adapter Settings. While holding `CTRL`, click your wireless and Ethernet adapters. Then, right click on either one. Click Bridge.

Once they are bridged, this *should* work. This doesn't always work for me but it usually does. It's "selective" :) . Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before using RP2 and RPB+. I would recommend using the following site which does a good job breaking it down.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7.html